# Thread safety of method

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I see the following contruct for a mutable class:

```
public class Doubtful
{

    public static Doubtful getInstance()
    {
        DoubtfulContext doubtfulcontext;//LOCAL HEAP VARIABLE
        //...
        doubtfulcontext = new DoubtfulContext(s1, new PrincipalName(s),
            DefaultConfig.getInstance());
        //...
        doubtfulcontext.setDoubtfulStore(new DoubtfulStore(new File(s2)));
        doubtfulcontext.setKeyTab(...);
        doubtfulcontext.setSupportedEncryptionTypes(ai);
        //...
        return new Doubtful(doubtfulcontext);
    }

    // ...
}
```

While Doubtful  may be non-mutable,but DoubtContext is definitely mutable.
Is this thread-safe?
What is the relevance of a local heap variable here?

Comment: Yes local variables are thread-safe. They are created when method is invoked, and destroyed when method ends.

Comment: "Local heap variable" is a non-sequitur. It's a local variable, therefore logically on the stack. It would also really help if you'd give the variable and the type different names...

Comment: the method seems to be thread safe as long you are not using any variables of the singleton `DefaultConfig.getInstance()`.

Comment: @vikingsteve: To follow Java naming conventions to start with - and for clarity. Otherwise when you see `Foo.doSomething()` it's not obvious whether that's a static method within the `Foo` type, or an instance method call via the `Foo` variable.

Comment: @vikingsteve: Nope - it was the capital `D` that I was more concerned with. Variable names should be in camelCase rather than PascalCase. (I hadn't actually noticed that the names *were* different - just by case *in the middle of the name*.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I will delete all my comments here since the discussion is kind of pointless and not helpful to the question...

Answer (score 1):

Local variables are confined to the executing thread.They exist on the executing thread's stack and are not accessible to other threads. And this makes the execution of `getInstance` method thread safe.

As you have said `Doubtful` is immutable, and that makes it thread safe: multiple threads can work with the same `Doubtful` instance without effecting others working with the same `Doubtful` instance. Because the threads cannot change the instance variables (`Doubtful` is immutable) and method local variables are confined to the executing thread.

Now `DoubtfulContext` is mutable and you are publishing a reference to the `DoubtfulContext` instance which is created locally in the method `getInstance`:

```
doubtfulcontext = new DoubtfulContext(s1, new PrincipalName(s),
        DefaultConfig.getInstance());
...
return new Doubtful(doubtfulcontext);//Publishes the reference to DoubtfulContext
```

which would violate the stack confinement. And there is a possibility that multiple threads can get access to the shared, mutable data of the same `DoubtfulContext` instance. If `DoubtfulContext` is a non-thread-safe object, then this would break your program.

Consider a thread `T1` that invokes `getInstance` to get an instance of `Doubtful` and after that it might share the `DoubtfulContext` reference (that came along with `Doubtful`) with other threads:

```
1. Doubtful doubtful = Doubtful.getInstance();
2. DoubtfulContext doubtfulContext = doubtful.getDoubtfulContext();
3. new Thread(new SomeRunnable(doubtfulContext)).start();
4. doubtfulContext.chnageSomeState();
```

At line no 3, it creates a new thread of execution with the `DoubtfulContext`. Now two threads have the same `DoubtfulContext`. If `DoubtfulContext` is non-thread-safe (having non-synchronized access to instance  variables), then this would break the thread safety of the program.

Answer (score 0):

This construction looks threadsafe, if there is no method or function to access the `doubtfulcontext` elsewhere in the class (and if the `doubtfulcontext` is not modified either), and if... Basically if you use it right, it is threadsafe.

There are a lot of *ifs* in that sentence. It would be preferable to make the `DoubtfulContext` non-mutable also.

Comment: even if the doubtfulcontext is accessing a file? I don't think this class is thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what this code does to say for certain if it is the right choice.  The question of thread safety is a question of what is mutable and if that object will ever be seen by more than one thread.  Creating a new object that is stateful, but will only ever be seen by one thread is thread-safe.  Creating an immutable object with all immutable members is thread-safe whether you return a new one or the same one repeatedly.

If you have mutable state, you have to know if the object will be seen by more than one thread.  If yes, then you need to take measures to ensure that the mutable things are thread-safe.

Several options:

- Make all of it immutable.  Initialize it in a static block and store it in a static variable (I'm not really a big fan of statics - it would be cleaner and more flexible use a dependency injection framework like Guice and inject it - then the decision about whether it's a singleton or not is made at startup time).
- If `doubtfulContext` is not shared, and is the **only** thing which is stateful - then it is stateful, but any future caller will get a new instance of it, then your method is fine.  If the `doubtfulContext` will be passed between threads later, you may need to make that thread-safe independently
- If you want to optimize by, say, only reading the same file once and sharing an object that represents the file, then you will need some kind of thread-safe cache